# How can I sort lines in file starting at nth character?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a file as follows: 
1 pineapple \n
2 apple \n

I would like to sort it starting nth character in each line, where n will be given.

For example if n=2, the file should be sorted as 2 apple \n 1 pineapple \n as 'a' is before 'p'

If n = 4 then sorted file should be 1 pineapple \n 2 apple \n as 'i' is before 'p'

How can I achieve this?

Sorting at 1st (0th) character works perfectly well. I am following this link: https://javaconceptoftheday.com/how-to-sort-a-text-file-in-java/

Implemented code is as follow:

```
String inputFile = 'test.txt';
String outputFile = 'output.txt';

FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
String inputLine;
List<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    lineList.add(inputLine);
}
fileReader.close();

Collections.sort(lineList);

FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputFile);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
for (String outputLine : lineList) {
    out.println(outputLine);
}
out.flush();
out.close();
fileWriter.close();
```

The above code works properly, however sorting starting at nth character on each line is not implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a custom comparator that takes a substring of each line:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(inputFile))
     .sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.substring(n))
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Files` class and sort the lines in a Stream. Finally you can save the result using the `Files` class again:

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("test.txt"))) {
    List<String> sortedLines = lines
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(line -> line.substring(n)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Files.write(Paths.get("output.txt"), sortedLines);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Alternatively you can use `line.charAt(n)` instead of `line.substring(n)` if you only want to sort by a single char.

Answer (score 1):

Create a comparator and use substring to create a substring starting at the n'th position and then compare based on that.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparator-interface-java/